# How to burn a CD-ROM from a Mac for Solaris; getting mangled filenames on mount

Tags: macos, mount, burning, compact-disc, solaris

I would like to burn a CD using a Mac (10.5) which I can then access from a Solaris 10 x86 machine.

This partially works:

1. Insert blank CD and let the Finder open it so it creates a "Recordable CD" window for it.
2. Drag the files to be burned into the "Recordable CD" window
3. Burn (there are no options except for speed)

Then to mount in Solaris:

```
mount -f hsfs -o ro /dev/dsk/foo /mnt/bar
```

The problem here is that Solaris will see all the filenames as lower case and it will only allow each file name to contain one period (these are HSFS limitations).  [Apple's help](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/8398.html) says they support the Rock Ridge and Joliet extensions which allow longer file names.

I have also tried using Toast with both the "Mac & PC" and "ISO 9660" options but I get the same results when mounting in Solaris.

Is there some combination of burning tools/options and mount options that will make this work?

Comment: you need ISO9660 extensions -- Rock Ridge and/or Joliet are two ways to do that.  or you could try burning as a UDF filesystem.

Comment: Solaris' man mount_hsfs: http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-5166/mount-hsfs-1m?a=view

Comment: I believe the Rock RIdge and Joliet extensions are present on the disc.  The Apple page I linked to above states that they are included on the disc.  Also, when trying the disc in a WinXP machine, it shows the correct filenames which indicates to me it is seeing the extensions.

Comment: I also tried the UDF option in Toast with the same results (8.3 filenames only when mounted in Solaris).

Answer (score 1):

The command line tool hdiutil might work:

http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html

Comment: Of particular note are the `-iso` and `-joliet` options to the `makehybrid` subcommand.

Answer (score 0):

I thought *Finder* included Joliet extensions by default, but as Nate suggested you might try using *hdiutil* to generate your image.

Also, you might try forcing the use of Joliet extensions to ISO 9660 when mounting on Solaris:

```
mount -f hsfs -o ro,joliet /dev/dsk/foo /mnt/bar
```

The [hsfs manpage](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2254/hsfs-7fs/index.html) seems to indicate that it should detect and use Joliet extensions if present, but it is worth trying mentioning it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use the ClI use `Disk Utility.app` (`/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app`).